# Couldn't find or load main class error in VIM

Tags: java, vim

I am quite new to VIM and trying to run a small java code to test whether its working or not but its showing error.

```
Error: Couldn't find or load main class test.java
```

This the command I used:

```
:!java test.java
```

My Code:

```
public class test{

    public static void main(string[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

I tried to fix it by following some some question in this site but couldn't make it.
Ex: `:!java -cp test.java`

This is the the Java Plugin I installed for VIM [LINK](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=245)
However, as the above plugin offers F5 to do all the process, its showing an error.

```
:!jikes + E test.java >c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\VIeA690.tmp 2>&1 shell returned 1 (1 of 2): 'jikes' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

So, I wonder if anyone could help on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to *compile* the java source file then run the compiled *class* file:

```
javac test.java
java test
```

From within `vim`, the keystrokes would be:

```
:!javac test.java ; java test
```

but that's an awful lot to type in to compile and run. I'd tend to just open up another window and run a script (called something like `x` to minimise keystrokes) to compile and run, leaving me to only need saving in the `vim` window.

However, the plug-in you installed is supposed to make that *easier* by assigning the save, compile and run operations to a function key `F5` so I'm not sure why you're not doing that.

Based on your comment that you're seeing:

> javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

there's a *very* good chance you don't have a Java compiler installed. At a bare minimum, it's not in your path. You need to fix that first. While things like Eclipse come with their own compiler, you generally need to install and configure something like `javac` if you're using something like `vim`.

In any case, `java` runs *class* files - it doesn't compile source files.

Comment: Its not working. Its showing " javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

however, I tried this before.

Comment: Then you don't have a java compiler in you path. You need to get that set up. In fact, if you can't run javac from a command line you probably don't even have one _installed._

Comment: We call that thing to compile and run "make". *runs*

Comment: actually, I installed JDK and JRE with Netbeans. I think it didn't set the path. But now, I added a path variable "C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.0 Runtime\bin" but its now working.

Comment: I could actually use F5 to run using in VIM but its even showing some error.
`:!jikes + E test.java >c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\VIeA690.tmp 2>&1 shell returned 1
(1 of 2): 'jikes' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: @Surya, by default it uses jikes to compile - you can either install that or fiddle with the `makeprg` option within the script. If you just want to compile and run, I'd still suggest doing that in a different window with a batch file (or makfile) rather than fiddling with options.